# Using Semantic UI and jQuery with Webpack

Tags: jquery, webpack, semantic-ui

I'm trying to use Semantic UI and jQuery with Webpack. Seemingly a very simple concept, but made impossibly complex in this case. I can't find a solution on the web that demonstrates both jQuery and Semantic with Webpack. 
The problem I'm having is that I've had semantic and jquery load via the index.html through a CDN. Now that I want to move them to the bundle, I need both to be available globally.

I've used:

```
 new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    'jQuery': "jquery",
    "window.jQuery": "jquery"
}),
```

Though I can't test if it works since semantic loads before hand and tries to use jQuery which is not available. I want semantic to be available globally as well, as I don't think its something i can import explicitly.

Thanks

Comment: do you have jquery available in your project path via npm ?

Comment: Yes I do. I figure out the problem and it was silly enough to merit a serious answer here.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This was resolved by simply remembering to delete the node_modules directory and reinstall all via `npm install`. 
All my previous attempts were causing a mishmash in the installed packages dir and eventually misreporting non existent problems.

Moral of this story: when in doubt, recreate your node_modules!